# Obtain a new token by refresh token with google_sign_in Flutter

Tags: flutter, google-signin, google-fit

I'm writing an application that call google fit rest api from Flutter.

I need to sign with google using (https://pub.dev/packages/google_sign_in).
I can obtain a token without problem (see [Did anyone manage to get the id token from google sign in (Flutter)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52458968/did-anyone-manage-to-get-the-id-token-from-google-sign-in-flutter)) but how to obtain a new token when it is expired?

I dont' want to ask to the user to login and obtain a new token every hour

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this in 2 ways.

1. You can use the [API](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2).
2. I don't know if this is standard but you can do a `silent login` every time the user opens the app, the silent log logs into the user account without user interaction and this way you have a new token. Like this:

```dart
import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart';
 // you may only login with google, delete hide part if not
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart' hide EmailAuthProvider; 

//...

Future<void> silentSignIn() async {
    try {
      final GoogleSignIn googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();
      final GoogleSignInAccount? googleUser =
          await googleSignIn.signInSilently();  // silent login
      if (googleUser != null) {
        final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth =
            await googleUser.authentication;
        final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
          accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
          idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
        );
        await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(credential);
        print('User silently signed in with Google.');
      } else {
        print('No user signed in silently.');
        // Optionally, redirect to a sign-in page
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error during silent sign-in: $e');
      // Handle errors or redirect to a manual sign-in page
    }
  }
```

Comment: Hi, using the api seem to be impossible because my token come from a Android client id and I doesn't have a "secret" key. The second options is something I hadn't thought of and is very promising and seem to works, thanks

Comment: Oh yes for sure, I just tried and seem to works, thanks ;)

Comment: It would be nice if you can mention an article where it explains how to update it via API. For me, the second method is giving the same token! Maybe I need to wait for an hour before testing it.

Comment: You are AMAZING! I've been working on this problem for so long and your solution was so simple and easy to implement. Thanks!

Comment: @HudsonKim Happy to help

Comment: this solution is not working and i'am always getting the same old token ...

Comment: Solution 2 doesn't work for me on android (works for iOS). It gives the same token again. I have posted code snippet from the plug in codes on plugins repo issue (https://github.com/googlesamples/google-signin-unity/issues/24#issuecomment-757544151) and seems to be doing it by design, is there any workaround?

Comment: An `access token` is not the same as `refresh token`, Currently, The official google_sign_in plugin does not support returning refresh token https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/45847

Answer (score 0):

Before calling '.signIn()' method make sure that GoogleSignInAccount variable type has 'forceCodeForRefreshToken' set up with **true**.

After that take 'serverAuthCode' and make a request to  https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token with the next body

`'access_type': 'offline', tokenType: <serverAuthCode>, 'grant_type': 'code', 'client_secret': <yourClientSecret>, 'client_id': <yourClientId>, 'redirect_uri': <yourMiddleWare>,`.

In response you will get that refresh_token.