# Google sign in for flutter web - exchange authorization code for refresh and access tokens

Tags: flutter, google-signin

I am using google_sign_in_web 0.10.2 https://pub.dev/packages/google_sign_in_web and following the posted [example](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/main/packages/google_sign_in/google_sign_in/example/lib/main.dart)

Here is some of the relevant code:

```
GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn(
  scopes: [
    'email',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly',
  ],
);


  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
            _googleSignIn.onCurrentUserChanged.listen((GoogleSignInAccount? account) {
          setState(() {
            _currentUser = account;
          });
          if (_currentUser != null) {
            _handleGetContact(_currentUser!);
          }
        });
        _googleSignIn.signInSilently();
      }
```

I can't find a method to exchange the authorization code for refresh and access tokens

Edit: Ok, I found the access token:

Once you have the `_currentUser` as above you do

```
final authentication = await _currentUser.authentication;

print(authentication.accessToken);
```

I still need the refresh token

Comment: Seems that the refresh token is not available through Google sign in: https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/1079.

Comment: possible Duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/q/62230448/1841839

Comment: @DaImTo the answer does not say how get the refresh_token, only posts an alternative. To me that is no good, I need the refresh_token explicitly

Comment: Signin is authentication it contains an id token and an access token.    Oauth2 is authorization and gets you an access token and a refresh token.    If you want access to the users google contacts then you need to use oauth2 to request authorization, not signin.

Comment: @DaImTo can you tell me the technical difference between one and the other?

Comment: Openid Connect or Signin or authorization, proves that a user is the one behind the machine.  A user had to have logged in to result in an id token you will only have access to the users profile information.      Oauth2 is how we request authorization for our applications to access private user data.  you are given an access token which grants your application access to the users data for a limited time. There is no way to know the calls are coming from the user and not something automated in your application.  The refresh token can also be given which will allow your app to access the data

Comment: Authentication, User is present and signs in.   Authorization grants an application access to a users data, no user need be present when the application accesses the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GoogleSignIn provides the idToken beside the accessToken.

```
final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleSignInAuthentication =
        await googleSignInAccount.authentication;

googleSignInAuthentication.accessToken
googleSignInAuthentication.idToken
```

Please refer to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/62230577/14729495

Comment: Is the idToken the refresh token?

Comment: As described in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/62230577/14729495 the idToken gets used to refresh the credentials.